# SQL: Conditional where clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, where-clause

**UPDATE: We were advised that it is possible that values for both parameters will not be provided. In such case, there should be no filter for both mobile number and email address.**

I'm having a hard time identifying what's wrong with my query. Basically, I have two variables

```
@EmlAdd
@MblNum
```

What I want to do is to search using the following rules:
at least one of the two variables must have a value
If I only supply value for email address , it must ignore the filter for mobile number
If I only supply value for mobile number, it must ignore the filter for email address

What's happening with my solution so far is that:
if values for 2 variables were supplied: IT WORKS
if only one of the variables has value: DOESN'T WORK

```
DECLARE
@EmlAdd AS VARCHAR(100),
@MblNum AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @EmlAdd = ''
SET @MblNum = '5555555'

SELECT
    USER_ID,
CONTACT_VALUE
FROM
TBL_CONTACTS
WHERE
(
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @MblNum OR @MblNum = '')
        OR
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @EmlAdd OR @EmlAdd = '')
)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried any of the answer given ?? i think there are 2 answer which i think right

Comment: Yeah, with a bit of tweaking, @devart's solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @EmlAdd VARCHAR(100)
    , @MblNum VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
      @EmlAdd = ''
    , @MblNum = '5555555'

SELECT [USER_ID], CONTACT_VALUE
FROM dbo.TBL_CONTACTS
WHERE CONTACT_VALUE IN (@MblNum, @EmlAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is if MblNum is blank OR if EmlAdd is blank return everything.

You may want to change the middle OR to an AND.

```
WHERE
(
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @MblNum OR @MblNum = '')
        AND
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @EmlAdd OR @EmlAdd = '')
)
```

that way the MblNum must match the CONTACT_VALUE AND the EmlAdd must match or be empty and visa versa. Now if you include both paramters then they both must match for the and.  If you still want either one to match then drop the check for an empty parameter,

```
WHERE CONTACT_VALUE = @MblNum OR CONTACT_VALUE = @EmlAdd
```

If either parameter is empty it shouldn't match CONTACT_VALUE and will be ignored.

Comment: Contact_Value is a column that will contain both email address and mobile number. Using AND will not return any value if both email address and mobile number were given.

Comment: @AgentX44 I wasn't sure if it was the same column or not.  If it was, the second solution will work, if they are different, the first column will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **OR @MblNum = ''** and  **OR @EmlAdd = ''**

When only one parameter has a value set the other will equal **''** (0 length string) and therefore the logical condition will be met on every call.

```
DECLARE
@EmlAdd AS VARCHAR(100),
@MblNum AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @EmlAdd = ''
SET @MblNum = '5555555'

SELECT
    USER_ID,
CONTACT_VALUE
FROM
TBL_CONTACTS
WHERE
(
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @MblNum)
        OR
    (CONTACT_VALUE = @EmlAdd)
        OR
    (@EmlAdd='' AND @MblNum='')
)
```

Comment: I did not get this part: SET EmlAdd = ' OR MblNum = ''
SET MblNum = '5555555'

Answer (score 0):

u are almost there, replace '' to is null

```
DECLARE @SAMPLE TABLE
(
[USER_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[CONTACT_VALUE] NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @SAMPLE 
VALUES 
('5555555'),
('Email@Yahoo.com')

DECLARE
@EmlAdd AS VARCHAR(100),
@MblNum AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @EmlAdd = ''
SET @MblNum = '5555555'

SELECT
USER_ID,
CONTACT_VALUE
FROM
@SAMPLE
WHERE
```

--the changes is here, replace '' to is null, as this is standard query practise , cheer =)

```
(@EmlAdd is null or CONTACT_VALUE =@EmlAdd)
or
(@MblNum is null or CONTACT_VALUE = @MblNum)
```

Comment: This won't work because if EmlAdd is null the query will match every row.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're only searching a single data column you don't have to be so clever... unless you've neglected to provide other pertinent information.

```
DECLARE @EmlAdd As varchar(100)
      , @MblNum As varchar(100);

SET @EmlAdd = '';
SET @MblNum = '5555555';

/* Optional (recommended)
-- Set values to NULL if blank string is passed
SET @EmlAdd = NullIf(@EmlAdd, '');
SET @MblNum = NullIf(@MblNum, '');
*/

-- If both variables are NULL then no search criteria
IF Coalesce(@EmlAdd, @MblNum) IS NULL THEN
  BEGIN
    SELECT USER_ID
         , CONTACT_VALUE
    FROM   TBL_CONTACTS;
  END
-- At least one variable is not NULL so let's look for it
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT USER_ID
         , CONTACT_VALUE
    FROM   TBL_CONTACTS
    WHERE  CONTACT_VALUE IN (@EmlAdd, @MblNum);
  END
;
```

Comment: I was able to use your solution as well as @devart's solution, but what he provided was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
@EmlAdd AS VARCHAR(100),
@MblNum AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @EmlAdd = ''
SET @MblNum = '5555555'

SELECT USER_ID, CONTACT_VALUE
FROM
TBL_CONTACTS
WHERE
(
  (CONTACT_VALUE = case when @MblNum = '' then @EmlAdd else case when @EmlAdd = '' then @MblNum  end end)

)
```